# If $\triangle ABC \cong \triangle XYZ$, is it "illegal" to say $\overline{AB}\cong\overline{YX}$ (instead of $\overline{XY}$)?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Question about corresponding sides of congruent triangles.

I know that if triangle $ABC$ is congruent to triangle $XYZ$ that side $AB$ is congruent to side $XY$; side $BC$ is congruent to side $YZ$; etc.  But is it "illegal" to say $AB$ is congruent to $YX$?  If so, why?  Isn't that statement still true?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Well, as $\overline YZ$ and $\overline ZY$ are by standard geometry notation standards the same object (the line segment determined by the two points $Y$ and $Z$) that is perfectly legal and valid.  But you get dinged for style points.  (Of course, we can do orientated geometry where direction matters.  Then they are not the same thing at all.)

Comment: *"But is it 'illegal' to say $AB$ is congruent to $YX$? [...] Isn't that statement still true?"* Well, the statement is *true*. Why? Maybe *because "$\triangle ABC\cong\triangle XYZ$" means (in part) $AB\cong XY$, and because $XY\cong YX$, and because of the transitivity of $\cong$.* Or, maybe *because "$\triangle ABC\cong\triangle XYZ$" means the sides opposite $C$ and $Z$ are $\cong$, and because "$XY$" and "$YX$" represent the same segment.* Either way, early stages of geometry tend to be *very* strict about stating each "and because" out loud; omitting them *might* be considered "illegal".